# Contract Self-Destruct

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, selfdestruct

Is there a programmatic(web3) way to know if an address has once been a contract and made a selfdestruct?

I can see it on Etherscan's transaction page, but is there a proper way to check this?

Comment: A normal full node would not retain such information. You likely need to have an archive node and then you can call `getCode()` JSON-RPC for historical blocks. Or you can build your own index by walking through all blockchain data.

Comment: but what if i don't know the block number which the selfdestruct happened in?

Comment: Do a binary search over all blocks.